# SQL query to select everything from 1 table and 1 column(same name as in table 1) from another table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables.
table1 :

```
Products:
ProductId Category Model Price Quantity
```

table2:

```
OrderLines:
OrderId ProductId Quantity
```

table3:

```
Orders:
OrderId CustomerId
```

(theres also a customer table but it doesnt matter)

Now I want to select all the products data from Products table that have ProductId = ProductId in OrderLines table, but get the quantity data (of those same products) from the OrderLines table.

Tried all kinds of queries, couldn't find one that works.

heres the last thing i kind of tried:

```
 SELECT tb1.* ,tb2.[Quantity] 
 FROM [Products] tb1, [OrderLines] tb2 
 WHERE tb1.[ProductId] IN (
    SELECT [ProductId] FROM [OrderLines] WHERE OrderId = @orderId)    
 INNER JOIN [OrderLines] tb2 ON[Products].Quantity = [OrderLines].Quantity";
```

didn't worked.

any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

sample data:
Orders:
OrderId CustomerId
1         2

OrderLines:
OrderId   ProductId   Quantity
1           3          1
1           4           5

Products:
ProductId Category Model Price Quantity
3          "wow"     "hd" 30     5
4            "yay"   "sd" 50     60
5           "wow"    "ss"  12   5

expected output:
array of products:
each object is type Product, having the same fields in as in the table. (already defined it's class).
first object in the array is:
productId = 3, Category="wow",Model="hd", price=30,Quantity =
 1  (**1! not 5)
2nd object:
productId = 4, Category="yay",Model="sd",price=50,Quantity=5

I am using c# in visual studio, Winforms. 
database is Access.
this is the function:

```
public Product[] GetProductsByOrderId(int orderId)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ArrayList arrProducts = new ArrayList();

            //"SELECT tb1.* ,tb2.[Quantity] FROM [Products] tb1, [OrderLines] tb2 WHERE tb1.[ProductId] IN (SELECT [ProductId] FROM [OrderLines] WHERE OrderId = @orderId) INNER JOIN [OrderLines] tb2 ON[Products].Quantity = [OrderLines].Quantity"
            string cmdStr = "SELECT p.*, ol.Quantity as OrderLineQuantity from Products as p    inner join    OrderLines as ol    on p.Id = ol.ProductId";

            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr))
            { 
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderId", orderId);
                ds = GetMultipleQuery(command);
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch { }
            foreach (DataRow tType in dt.Rows)
            {
                Product productData = new Product();

                productData.ProductId = int.Parse(tType[0].ToString());
                productData.Category = tType[1].ToString();
                productData.Model = tType[2].ToString();
                productData.Price = double.Parse(tType[3].ToString());
                productData.Quantity = int.Parse(tType[4].ToString());
                arrProducts.Add(productData);
            }
            return (Product[])arrProducts.ToArray(typeof(Product));
        }
```

Sorry and I Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: (1) Sample data and desired results would really help.  (2) MySQL does not use square braces.  Are you sure you have tagged the question correctly?

Comment: Sample data and expected output data plz?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  You tag MYSQL, but your code looks like SQL Server.  Which one is this????

Comment: So add Access tag to your question so that people who do not know Access won't waste their time reading this question.

Comment: @Eric done.done.

Comment: Is this supposed to be Microsoft Access? Because you use the Access tag, which specifically says it's not supposed to be used for Microsoft Access. Please tag your question appropriately. And don't tag your question as C# or include C# code if it's not actually relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual query that works is:

```
SELECT p.ProductId, p.Category, p.Model, p.Price, o.Quantity 
FROM [Products] p 
INNER JOIN [OrderLines] o ON p.ProductId = o.ProductId 
WHERE o.OrderId = @orderId 
ORDER BY p.ProductId
```

Thanks for @Hogan for getting me started in the right direction.

edited thanks to lucas mention, deleted the WHERE IN SELECT...

Comment: If you're doing an inner join on ProductId the following `WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ...)` is completely reduntant.

Comment: @Lucas but I have to have someway to select ProductId(s) that are part of the Orders table, with that OrderId.   none of the solutions uses parameter that way (@orderId) which is necessary.

Comment: @Piepypye -- Welcome to stack overflow.  While I understand many people who come from other websites expect just a conversation, that is not actually a method that make stack overflow work.  It is important to upvote answer that are correct and help and not just post your own answer.  This encourages people to help you and is much better than saying "Thanks for Hogan".  Upvoting is the way of saying thanks on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you four columns from product and 1 from orderlines based on a join.

```
SELECT p.productId, p.category, p.model, p.price, o.quantity
from products p
join orderlines o on p.productid = o.productid
```

> Small style note -- don't use the plural for the table name.  eg use
>   product not products and orderline not orderlines.  No good reason except that is how everyone does it.

Comment: @dbmitch -- thanks!  I'd say that was a typo not a spelling error, but good eye.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, ol.Quantity as OrderLineQuantity from
    Products as p
    inner join
    OrderLines as ol
    on p.Id = ol.ProductId
```

Comment: Please add an explanation and not just a raw code dump.

Comment: @mason It's a very basic and straightforward join, really not much to explain there. If you look at Ops question he already uses an inner join so I assume he knows what it is. If other people come across this question and can't understand an inner join it's better to let them figure out basic SQL by themselves than try to hold their hand to say 1+1=2.

Comment: Pardon me mason, are you testing a "Please add an explanation and not just a raw code dump." spambot that downvotes answers? Do you consider 4 lines a "dump"? Have you considered the simplicity of the question is enough to warrant downvotes? Lucas said it finely.

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.ProductId,sum(ol.Quantity)
from Products p
inner join orderlines ol on p.ProductID=ol.ProductID
group by p.ProductId
```

Comment: Please add an explanation, not just a raw code dump.